# Computing the short time windowed Fourier Transform

Tags: matlab, fft

Could anyone suggest a method for computing the short time windowed fourier transform of a given signal, also known as the windowed fourier transform, of a signal with altering periodicity? Consider this example data series:

```
t = 1:365;
x = cos((2*pi)/12*t)+randn(size(t));
```

I understand the principles behind the method, but trying to implement it in matlab is another matter. I this example is not sufficient to provide an answer, any solution to a signal with varying periodicity would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about this File Exchange solution? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31592-short-time-fourier-transform

Comment: ...and how about [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/STFT_Matlab.html)?